# Spring Cloud Feign/Ribbon with corporate proxy

Tags: spring-boot, proxy, netflix, netflix-feign, netflix-ribbon

I want to consume a REST service from the outside world behind a corporate proxy with authentication.

How do I configure Spring Boot + Spring Cloud Feign/Ribbon to use our proxy?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you're looking for something like this:

```
import feign.Feign;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Proxy;
...
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("proxy-url", 1234));
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().proxy(proxy).build();
Feign.builder()
    .client(new feign.okhttp.OkHttpClient(okHttpClient))
    .target(...);
```

You just have to additionally add `compile 'io.github.openfeign:feign-okhttp:9.5.0'` to your project.

The `target` clause contains your defined Interface. Further reference: https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign

Comment: I will try it. Thanks

Comment: Can you please explain how to use this piece of code to make feign client work behind a corporate proxy, please?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there is actually a much easier solution.

The following information will be helpful (also for more advanced use cases):

- [Spring Cloud Commons HTTP Factories](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/reference/html/#http-clients)
- [Overriding Feign Defaults](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-openfeign/reference/html/#spring-cloud-feign-overriding-defaults)

OpenFeign Client can run with several HTTP Clients.
By default it uses `java.net.URLConnection`, but you can also use `ApacheHttpClient` or `OkHttpClient`.

### Using Apache Http Client

Here is what you can do to set a proxy using `ApacheHttpClient`:

1. Add the following two dependencies to your pom.xml:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
</dependency>
<!-- Dependency to switch HttpClient implementation from java.net.URLConnection to Apache HTTP Client -->
<!-- See also: FeignAutoConfiguration for details. -->
<!-- See also: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/reference/html/#http-clients -->
<!-- See also: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-openfeign/reference/html/#spring-cloud-feign-overriding-defaults -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
  <artifactId>feign-httpclient</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

In your app expose the following bean:

```java
// see: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/reference/html/#http-clients
@Bean
public HttpClientBuilder proxiedHttpClient() {
  String proxyHost   = "client-envoy";
  Integer proxyPort  = 80
  String proxyScheme = "http";

  return HttpClientBuilder.create()
                          .setProxy(new HttpHost(proxyHost, proxyPort, proxyScheme));
}
```

That's it - nothing else needs to be configured in `application.yaml` since `ApacheHttpClient` will be used by default, if it is on the classpath.

### Using Ok Http Client

To set a proxy using `OkHttpClient` you do a similar thing:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
  <artifactId>feign-okhttp</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

In your `application.yml` make sure to enable OkHttpClient and disable ApacheHttpClient:

```yaml
spring:
 cloud:
   httpclientfactories:
     ok:
       enabled: true
     apache:
       enabled: false

feign:
 okhttp:
   enabled: true
 httpclient:
   enabled: false
```

Instead of `HttpClientBuilder` expose a bean of type `OkHttpClient.Builder`.

Answer (score 0):

Spring cloud feign supports three underlying implementations:

1. Default
2. Apache HttpClient
3. OkHttpClient

**If using Default:**

Create this spring bean (say by defining inside class with `@Configuration` annotation), no changes required in application properties/yml:

```
  @Bean
  public Client feignClient() {
    return new Client.Proxied(
        null, null, new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(proxyHost, proxyPort)));
  }
```

**If using Apache HttpClient:**

> that means you have `feign.httpclient.enabled: true` in `application.yml` and below in your `pom.xml` or `build.gradle`:

```
pom.xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
    <artifactId>feign-httpclient</artifactId>
</dependency>

build.gradle
implementation 'io.github.openfeign:feign-httpclient'
```

Create this spring bean (say by defining inside class with `@Configuration` annotation):

```
  @Bean
  public CloseableHttpClient feignClient() {
    return HttpClientBuilder.create().setProxy(new HttpHost(proxyHost, proxyPort)).build();
  }
```

**If using OkHttpClient:**

> that means you have `feign.okhttp.enabled: true` in `application.yml` and below in your `pom.xml` or `build.gradle`:

```
pom.xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
    <artifactId>feign-okhttp</artifactId>
</dependency>

build.gradle
implementation 'io.github.openfeign:feign-okhttp'
```

Create this spring bean (say by defining inside class with `@Configuration` annotation):

```
  @Bean
  public OkHttpClient feignClient() {
    return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .proxy(new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(proxyHost, proxyPort)))
        .build();
  }
```